# How to use translations in Yii console application?

Tags: internationalization, yii, console-application

I have created a console Yii application that works as a background worker for a web app - it sends out emails and it needs to send them with translated messages.

For some reason however, the messages are not translated when using `Yii::t`

If I set the language to something else than english with `Yii::app->setLanguage('et_ee')`, and check that it is really changed with `Yii::app->getLanguage()` the texts are always in english.

When I run this same command from web, the texts are correctly translated.

I guess there must be something special I have to do for the translatiosn to work in a console application?

Answer (score 0):

I have this error to. I dont know how is fix it. I am get lang array trow require('path/to/message/ru/message.php') in to var and use it. It is wrong, but it is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `messages` component in your `console.php` configuration

```
'messages' => array(
  'class' => 'CDbMessageSource',
  'forceTranslation'=>true,
  'sourceMessageTable' => 'source_message',
  'translatedMessageTable' => 'translated_message',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add string (For example - russian languages):

```
'language' => 'ru'
```

in config/console.php.